# Android : How to pass my facebook session information to a webview

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing an android application where I have a webview. The user logs in using his facebook account to use the features of my app. I've done the facebook login using FacebookSDK.
Now I want to pass the facebook user information in that webview. To be clear, the website which I'm using in the webview has a login using facebook button. I want that the user not to give his facebook credentials in that webview - instead, I want to pass the session information to the website in the webview.
Any help is appreciated. I was recently checking spring framework as well, but I can't find anything helpful in that too!